# Does the iPhone / iPod Touch support bulk enterprise app deployment or would all customers have to buy from app store

Tags: iphone, deployment, enterprise

I'm just wondering if anybody knows if Apple provides deals to enterprises wanting to deploy an application to a large # of customers.  Or does every customer have to go to the app store and buy the application individually giving Apple the 30% cut of your app price.

Thanks

Comment: @RyuI am facing the same problem, can you please tell me the correct way that how can i publish my app with >3000 employees using IOS Enterprise program? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you develop an application that you want to distribute yourself,it must be digitally signed with a certificate issued by Apple. You must also provide your users with a distribution provisioning profile that allows their device to use the application.

http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf

Comment: But you have to have 500 employees and the installation process is too complex to be practical for external customers.

Comment: The 500-employee requirement is no longer in effect.

Comment: This document is pretty out of date, is there any updated version?  Most importantly, is a connection to iTunes still required to install the distribution profile?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they do [support enterprise deployments](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf)

Comment: Note that your company has to have more than 500 employees in order to get an enterprise license.

Comment: (This is no longer a requirement.)

Comment: @EricI am facing the same problem, can you please tell me the correct way that how can i publish my app with >3000 employees using IOS Enterprise program? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The >500 employee restriction (mentioned in some of the responses here) has just been removed within the past week. See:
[alternative-solutions-for-in-house-iphone-enterprise-app-distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309835/alternative-solutions-for-in-house-iphone-enterprise-app-distribution/3790758#3790758)