# Publish apps for iphone enterprise developer program

Tags: iphone, enterprise

if i'm on the iphone enterprise developer program for companies with >500 employees, do i still need to publish my app on the app store for clients to install the app?

Comment: @dsimI am facing the same problem, can you please tell me the correct way that how can i publish my app with 3000 employees using IOS Enterprise program? Thanks

Comment: Flagged as duplicate as OP says they found the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509513/does-the-iphone-ipod-touch-support-bulk-enterprise-app-deployment-or-would-all

Answer (score 6):

If you do not intend to publish apps to the App Store, then don't. The iPhone Enterprise Developer Program is designed not to allow you to publish apps to the App Store. For that you need to *also* enroll in the standard program.

From [Apple Developer's FAQ](http://developer.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise.html) for the enterprise program:

> If your company is enrolled in the Enterprise Program but would also like to distribute your application(s) to customers via the App Store, you will need to enroll in the iPhone Developer Program  as an Individual or as a Company.

Comment: so how do i distribute the app if not through appstore? i read the details from apple that it goes by "in-house". what does this mean?

Comment: The enterprise program only allows you to distribute the application file among employees with registered devices in your company, not to anybody else.

Comment: @BoltClockI am facing the same problem, can you please tell me the correct way that how can i publish my app with >3000 employees using IOS Enterprise program? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify - the enterprise developer program allows you to build apps so that you **do not  need to register the devices** in advance. However, you have to make sure that the apps you build are only used by employees, contractors, and "customers" (in very special situations). For more information check out the updated article "Apple iOS Enterprise Developer Program Summary" http://www.apperian.com/technote/Apple_iOS_Enterprise_Developer_Program

Comment: What do you mean by "customers" (in a very special situations)?

Answer (score 4):

The iOS Developer Enterprise Program is now open to all companies - see http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/ - they removed the 500+ employee limit. This will definitely help companies that want to roll out internal "in-house" apps.