# How can we distribute iOS build using Enterprise Account?

Tags: iphone, ios, testflight

How can we distribute iOS build, which is built by using Enterprise Account? Is there any possible to distribute via testflight account? Any help much appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: See this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509513/does-the-iphone-ipod-touch-support-bulk-enterprise-app-deployment-or-would-all

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of different ways to do this. Once you've got a .ipa file for the app, you can:

1. Distribute via iTunes, if your employees can sync their iOS devices with their laptops ([Apple Docs](https://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/#app43ad7eed))
2. By using the iOS Configuration utility, though this means you have to physically have the device ([Apple docs](https://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/#app43ad6ebd))
3. Over-the-air (iOS 4+), using an app store. You can do this through TestFlight, but the license restrictions on the Enterprise agreement don't go well with this kind of deployment. You'll need to either create and secure your own app store (like I've done for my employer) or use a third party service. Have a Google around for some good ones. There's plenty of documentation on how to do the deployment [here](https://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/#app43ad871e)
4. Some MDM suppliers like [MobileIron](http://www.mobileiron.com/) have app stores available. Some will even allow you to push apps onto enterprise devices (iOS 5+) without any need for human intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Other options are via email or putting it on the web for download (suggest you would want a website with a login to access it).