# Can we use enterprise account for apple beta testing we don't have developers account?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, enterprise, testflight

[How can we distribute iOS build using Enterprise Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502491/how-can-we-distribute-ios-build-using-enterprise-account)

Comment: Are you trying to beta test your own app? Who is the target audience?

Comment: @Dan Yes actually as tesflight is closed now i just want to send app to my client. Diawi,Hockeyapp are the options but my client want it only by apple beta test so what should i do ... is it not possible to upload build by enterprise account and not opening another developers account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i would recommend doing is asking them to provide you their test device UDIDs and add them to your developer portal. You would next want to add those same devices to your development provisioning profile associated with the solution.

Within XCode after you compile your app with the development prov profile you can supply them the IPAD and they will only be able to install it on those designated devices. This all of course hinges on whether or not you have room within your Enterprise account's 100 device limit. Speaking from experience there is no valid reason why a client wouldn't agree to this approach to validate a build.

Another option would be to sign it with your Enterprise Distribution Cert and provide the client a partially working version of the app. What you don't want to do is provide them a fully functional, Enterprise-signed IPA as they can easily distribute that internally and not look back. You could potentially embed watermarks all over the place, throw up dialog prompts every few minutes, etc.

Comment: Right but it means i need to open developers program from apple developer.....That was the only question

Comment: Based on your initial question it made it sound like you have an enterprise account already. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes i am having enterprise account already....and i don't have developers account. So thats only the question is pushing app to apples beta testing/app store using enterprise account possible?

Comment: Apple doesn't have a beta App Store that I'm aware of. How many users are you trying to beta-test this with?

Comment: 10 users....and actually  i was asking about beta testing using enterprise account not about beta App Store....

Comment: No as  I am not having 20 reputations

Answer (score 0):

We can use Hockey app even if we don't have apples developers account and share our IPA with client.